# Apche camel SFTP transfer failover not moving to the next active connection in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jsch

I have two active connections:

1.connectionA
2.connectionB

My LoadBalancer code looks like this:

```
methodA() {
configureOnExceptions();
LoadBalanceDefinition loadBalanceDefinition = 
         from(uri)
         .onCompletion().
         .onCompleteOnly()
         .process(successfulSubmissionProcessor)
         .end()
         .loadBalance()
         .failover(1, true, true, true); // maximumFailoverAttempts, inheritErrorHandler, roundrobin,                           //sticky

for (connection name: connectionList) {
     String route = build route using + connectionA or connectionB accordingly;
     loadBalanceDefinition.to(route);
}
loadBalanceDefinition.end();
}
    
private void configureOnExceptions() {
  onException(Throwable.class)
  .handled(false)
  .maximumRedeliveries(3)
  .redeliveryDelay(3000)
  .useOriginalMessage()
  .process(exceptionHandlingProcessor)
  .end();
}
```

Expectation:

1. When the connectionA throws exception: Maximum retries : 3 times
2. and move on to connectionB

Actual:

1. It did not move over to connectionB

Question:

1. Does failover = 1 and retries = 3 impact the moving on to next connection?
2. did i make any mistakes?